# How to create a regex that looks for a word in any combination?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, combinations

I am curious to know how to write a regex to replace the following I use for .htaccess managing my page urls. The point of the Regex is to identify any combination of letters whether they are upper or lower case so that I don't have to think of each combination like the following example....

```
RewriteRule ^(about-us|About-Us|About-us|ABOUT-US)$ about-us.php [L]
```

However what if I dont think of a combo, how can I write a regex that does this?

So far the closest I have come is...

```
^([about\-us|ABOUT\-US])$ about-us.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a complicated regex I suggest using `NC` (no case) flag to make your rule ignore case:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ about-us.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
^([aA]bout-[uU]s|ABOUT-US)$ about-us.php [L]
```

Comment: Why do you escape your hypens?  They are not in a character class.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this as the regex

```
^[aA][bB][oO][uU][tT]\-[uU][sS]$
```

It supports any combination of lower-case and upper-case.